# Download URLs in JSON file and save with a specific naming pattern

Tags: json, regex, awk, grep, jq

I'd like to download images and rename them by their index

The only thing I have is a jsonlines file which looks like this:

```
{"image": 136, "url": "https://enkistroy.ru/800/600/https/avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-zen_doc/1852570/pub_5dbb15dfba281e00b14b4174_5dbb2300e3062c00b072ecce/scale_1200"}
{"image": 137, "url": "https://forums.cdprojektred.com/index.php?attachments/unbenannt-jpg.6709974/"}
{"image": 138, "url": "https://64.media.tumblr.com/1309f93790c53ccacc333b28d12dac66/tumblr_p9fqienz291x5m66ko1_r1_1280.png"}
{"image": 139, "url": "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/4c/21/0c/4c210ca963cf4d52636615ac08126b05.jpg"}
```

I've tried using `jq tool, grep, wget and curl`

```
egrep -o 'https:[^\"]*jpg' images.json | xargs -n 1 curl -O
```

This only downloads https links with jpg files without renaming them

Maybe writing python script would be easier?

EDIT:

Tried this not sure how to rename with curl? `curl -O "#1.jpg"`

`jq -r '.url' images.json | parallel curl -O`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like this:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

idx=0
while IFS= read -r url; do
    (( idx++ ))
    sfx="${url##*.}"
    case "$sfx" in
        png ) ;;
        * ) sfx='jpg' ;;
    esac
    echo curl "$url" -o "${idx}.${sfx}"
done < <(jq -r '.url' "${1:-images.json}")
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
curl https://enkistroy.ru/800/600/https/avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-zen_doc/1852570/pub_5dbb15dfba281e00b14b4174_5dbb2300e3062c00b072ecce/scale_1200 -o 1.jpg
curl https://forums.cdprojektred.com/index.php?attachments/unbenannt-jpg.6709974/ -o 2.jpg
curl https://64.media.tumblr.com/1309f93790c53ccacc333b28d12dac66/tumblr_p9fqienz291x5m66ko1_r1_1280.png -o 3.png
curl https://i.pinimg.com/originals/4c/21/0c/4c210ca963cf4d52636615ac08126b05.jpg -o 4.jpg
```

The above assumes that any URL that doesn't end in `.png` is JPEG, massage to suit with whatever rules you're aware of for identifying the image types to use as the file suffixes or restrict the curl to only the JPEG files.

Obviously remove the `echo` when you're done testing and want to actually execute the `curl`.

To use the image data as the index (see the comments below):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -r idx url; do
    sfx="${url##*.}"
    case "$sfx" in
        png ) ;;
        * ) sfx='jpg' ;;
    esac
    echo curl "$url" -o "${idx}.${sfx}"
done < <( jq -j '.image, " ", .url, "\n"' "${1:-images.json}" )
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
curl https://enkistroy.ru/800/600/https/avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-zen_doc/1852570/pub_5dbb15dfba281e00b14b4174_5dbb2300e3062c00b072ecce/scale_1200 -o 136.jpg
curl https://forums.cdprojektred.com/index.php?attachments/unbenannt-jpg.6709974/ -o 137.jpg
curl https://64.media.tumblr.com/1309f93790c53ccacc333b28d12dac66/tumblr_p9fqienz291x5m66ko1_r1_1280.png -o 138.png
curl https://i.pinimg.com/originals/4c/21/0c/4c210ca963cf4d52636615ac08126b05.jpg -o 139.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this works like a charm. However, by index I meant value after `"image"`:  if there is a broken link all indices are messed up. I'll try replacing (( idx++ )) with something like `sed -E 's/.[^:]*..(.[^,]*).*(\..*)".*/\1\2/;/^$/d' images.json`

Comment: Obviously that's not the right approach. You're already using `jq`, just have it print both the image number and the url.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, appreciate it. I reckon `jq` is the right tool for processing JSON data

Answer (score 0):

*Maybe writing python script would be easier?*

Python has built-in module [`imghdr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imghdr.html) which comes handy if you have image file, but do not know in what format. Let say that you downloaded your `https://64.media.tumblr.com/1309f93790c53ccacc333b28d12dac66/tumblr_p9fqienz291x5m66ko1_r1_1280.png`
and save it under name `138`, to detect what format of image it actually is launch `python` in same catalog and do

```
import imghdr
imgformat = imghdr.what("138")
print(imgformat)
```

output

```
jpeg
```

Built-in [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) module allow to easily change name to include this extension, i.e.:

```
import imghdr
import os
filename = "138"
imgformat = imghdr.what("138")
if imgformat:
    os.rename(filename, filename + "." + imgformat)
```

Note `if imgformat:` is used so when image format was not recognized there is no operation